# How to print n numbers from text file containg n numbers without repeating them?

Tags: python, file

Lets say I have text file containing n integers :

```
1
1
2
3
2
4
3
1
5
6
3
5
2
6
```

How to program a function to print those integers without repeating them?
My output should be :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Note : Output should not be a text file.
Note2 : File contains n integers.

Comment: Create an empty set. Read each line of the file interpreting each line as an integer. If that value doesn't exist in the set, print it and add it to the set

Comment: You should include your attempt in your question to help us guide you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your integers live in a file named `numbers.txt`, you could do as follows:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    for number in set(f.readlines()):
        print(int(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those numbers in `set` and they will be unique after that you can print out those numbers wherever you want.

```py
set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3]) = {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: ok, but what if I have very long text file containing N numbers?

Comment: What makes you think that it matters how long the file is?

Comment: @helperman200 then also it will work but if you want to optimize the algorithm then you have to look into it, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add what you tried...pls, add to your question next time.

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')

##data ##"11232.....
no_repeats ="".join(set(data))
no_repeats = int(no_repeats)
print(no_repeats)
```